# clearTimeout test not working with jest.useFakeTimers()

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to migrate to the "modern" version of [`jest.useFakeTimers()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/next/jest-object#jestusefaketimersimplementation-modern--legacy), which is not the default in version 27.x.
I'm having some issues with my tests, since Jest keeps saying that functions like `clearTimeout` and `setInterval` are not jest mocks:

```js
// Poster.ts
// This is the class method I'm testing

startInterval(interval = 1800000) {
  this._interval && clearTimeout(this._interval)

  this._interval = (setInterval(
    () =>
      this.post()
        .then((result) => {
          this.runHandlers('autopostSuccess', result)
          return result
        })
        .catch((error) => this.runHandlers('autopostFail', error)),
    interval
  ) as unknown) as number
  return this._interval
}
```

```js
// Poster.test.ts
describe('startInterval method', () => {
  const p = new Poster({ client: {} })
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()
  })
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers()
  })

  it('should call clearTimeout (but only from the second use)', () => {
    const firstID = p.startInterval()
    expect(clearTimeout).not.toHaveBeenCalled() // This line fails with the following error
    p.startInterval()
    expect(clearTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(clearTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(firstID)
  })

  // ...
})
```

Error:

```
expect(received).not.toHaveBeenCalled()

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
```

So, it's complaining about the fact that `clearTimeout` is not a mock, even though I'm using `jest.useFakeTimers()`

Versions:

- `jest` @ 27.0.3
- `ts-jest` @ 27.0.2
- `typescript` @ 4.2.4
- Node @ 12.14.0

I'm sure I'm missing something here, maybe I'm using `useFakeTimers` in the wrong way, but neither the [method docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/next/jest-object#jestusefaketimersimplementation-modern--legacy) nor the [page on Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/next/timer-mocks) have helped me.

Does anybody know why my test is not working?

Comment: I have same issue with clearTimeout mock. Any news about this?

Comment: @eMko No, unfortunately. I haven't had the time to investigate further :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging I found hopefully correct approach.

Answer is in this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11447) discussion.

> Jest added spies to the fake timers automatically. We no longer do that, people need to do e.g. jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout') themselves.

And that works for me. Just add `jest.spyOn(global, 'clearTimeout')` and it should work. Maybe you even don't need `jest.useFakeTimers()` statement.